# selectOneMenu's Ajax event is not being called when it is updated by commandLink

Tags: ajax, jsf

When I manually change the selected value of *selectOneMenu*:

- *selectOneMenu's* selected value gets changed to '2'
- I get '2' on the console which means that the '*selectOneMenuAjaxEvent*' is WELL being invoked.
- I get one XHR request on the Network tab of Firebug.

BUT when I try to change the selected value by clicking on the commandLink:

- *selectOneMenu's* selected value gets changed to '2'
- I get nothing in the editor console which means that the '*selectOneMenuAjaxEvent*' is NOT being invoked.
- I get also no any XHR requests on the Network tab of Firebug which means this ajax event even not being sent.
- There is no any error shows up on the Firebug console.

Why is the *selectOneMenu's* ajax change event not being sent when the value changes by the commandLink?

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="mainForm">

        <h:selectOneMenu id="selectMenu" value="#{indexBean.selectedValue}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />

            <f:ajax listener="#{indexBean.selectOneMenuAjaxEvent}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:commandLink value="Change Selected Value"
                       action="#{indexBean.changeSelectedValue}"/>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**IndexBean**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class IndexBean implements Serializable {

    private String selectedValue = "1";

    public void changeSelectedValue(){
        selectedValue = "2";
    }

    public void selectOneMenuAjaxEvent(){
        System.out.println(selectedValue);
    }

    public String getSelectedValue() {
        return selectedValue;
    }
    public void setSelectedValue(String selectedValue) {
        this.selectedValue = selectedValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: "*BUT when I try to change the selected value by clicking on the commandLink*". This is completely out of my understanding as to why this is required. An `<h:commandLink>` triggers a synchronous POST request (unless `<f:ajax>` appropriately used) in which AJAX is not supposed to work.

Comment: The `selectOneMenuAjaxEvent` is tied to the `selectOneMenu`, not to the `commandLink` : the relying javascript sending the ajax request is triggered only when you interact with the `selectOneMenu`.

Comment: @Tiny In the real app I add a new value to the selectOneMenu. And after adding, I select the new value automatically. But when selecting values I need to execute some other functions and this is where ajax get them called. I've tried to avoid the real app's complexity with this sample codes.

Comment: @KorkiKorkig: Your comment only confuses things even more. What Tiny comments is totally valid. You code behaves as designed.

Comment: @Kukeltje Please just forget about the real app. I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work here and is it possible to make it work. So the answer is, `The is no way on the world to change a selectOneMenu's value by a commandLink and wait its ajax change event executes by himself. Because of the reasons that are described in the @Tiny's, @ForguesR's comments`

Comment: Think of it, why should the ajax change event of a selectOneMenu fire on a commandLink? It was already 'fired' when you interacted with the selectOneMenu. So there is totally no need to fire again on the commandLink. You seem to expect some behaviour that is not logical. If you use ajax to populate the model, the commandLink/Button is usually meant to just signal to the server side that you are finished editing/filling out or whatever. So the answer is : _"There is in the world no need to.... "_ (or you must be the first one to have a usecase that everybody missed and that is not an XY problem

Comment: Ah... wait... You seem to expect that if you set the value of a certain property, `selectedValue` in this case, serverside, the ajax event, that is triggered when you interact with the input control on the client side that corresponds with the property, is fire to. Sorry, no that is just not how it works, not how it is designed. And I've seen next to none usecases where this would come in handy. In the few I've seen, both the ajax event handler and the action on the commandLink call the same server side method.

Comment: @Kukeltje You mean that my best option is to add `actionListener="#{indexBean.changeSelectedValue}" action="#{indexBean.selectOneMenuAjaxEvent}"` to the commandLink?

Comment: No... Not the best, but it is an option. Since your actual usecase is unknown, it is hard to say what the 'best' solution is